# Parsing a Type using a GHC-Plugin

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

I'm working on a compiler plugin that should abort compilation if a declaration doesn't have a type that given as a plugin argument.

I think the function `Unify.tcMatchTy :: Type -> Type -> Maybe TCvSubstS` would do the trick. I can find one of the argument types from the inputs of the typechecker plugin, but the other comes in as a plugin argument. That is, as a `String`.

How do I, in a typechecker plugin, get a `Type` from a `String`? I tried using `parseType` followed by calls to `rnHsType` and `tcLHsType`, which does convert a `String` into `Type`. This seems to work for simple types, but it results in this kind of error when the string contains a type variable:

```
Text:0:0: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘a’

Text:0:0: error:
    • GHC internal error: ‘a’ is not in scope during type checking, but it passed the renamer
      tcl_env of environment: []
    • In the type ‘a -> b’
```

I'm probably missing some bit (or perhaps a huge chunk) of work here, but where should I look for it?

(Prefixing the input with a `forall a b.` caused a compiler panic)

Comment: .. tcMatchTy doesn't seem to work anyhow..